# How to validate multiple forms inline on a single IF?

Tags: php, yii

For logical and faster purposes, whenever you make PHP try two statements using an AND condition, if the first one fails he doesn't attempt to try the second one... for logical and faster purposes that is beautiful indeed, but on my case I would need to know if the second statement also didn't work, so I don't need to make an user go through the same page a lot of times because the mistake was different than before...

So, assuming I have this:

```
    if ($firstModel->validate() && $secondModel->validate()) {$sayCheese;}
```

How do I make it try both?

I did consider separating the models but I just want to know if there's an alternative.

Edit:
My form has multiple inserts for different models at the same time so the validation works beautifully if for a single model only, and since I need to try two or more at the same time, NOT stopping at the first statement is a MUST.

Comment: What about separate if-statements?

Comment: && is for checking if this and this and this is true then execute. If you want 1 of the 2 to be true and execute just use OR ||

Comment: I actually need to try both of them because they are different models on the system but both are required on an insert but making an OR I would have to allow one or another, and that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($firstTry & $thenTry) {$sayCheese;}
```

This will do a bitwise and, and check $thenTry even if $firstTry is false.

Edit : note I am just naively replying to your question, but I am not entirely sure why you would realistically want to do this.

Comment: But surely this lets you know one of these conditions is false. You would then have to write another if inside this if to decide which condition was false in order to return the correct error. So it is not actually saving any time or code

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes exactly. An if / else structure would be much cleaner.

Comment: But the idea is not saving time or code, the idea is for trying both statements so then I can have the errors set on the form based on both mistakes and not just one, I knew there was a way but I forgot how.

And I actually don't understand why I have so much negative votes, there was this question somewhere else?

Comment: @RafaelBoszko You most likely got downvoted because people here assume your coding approach is not elegant. But I understand that sometimes you have to do things in a certain way. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: I guess that every system has it's perks, right? Anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to split the checks and your if-condition

```
$firstTry = checkOne();
$thenTry = checkTwo();
if ($firstTry && $thenTry) {
    echo $sayCheese;
} else {
    echo "check 1: ".($firstTry ? 'ok' : 'bad')."<br>";
    echo "check 2: ".($firstTry ? 'ok' : 'bad')."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I consider that also but my form has one submit and three model updates, so it might be leaving information about one model or another empty.